Why does splitting extension field’s elements into several subfields doesn’t help solving discrete logs despite it helps computing exponentiations?
Let’s say I have 2 finite fields elements $A$ and $B$ in $GF_p^6$ having their discrete logarithm belonging to a large prime suborder/subgroup $s$ such as $p>s$.
$A$ and $B$ can be represented as the cubic extension of $GF_p^2$ by splitting their finite field elements. This give $A.x∈GF_p^2$ ; $A.y∈GF_p^2$ ; $A.z∈GF_p^2$ ; and $B.x∈GF_p^2$ ; $B.y∈GF_p^2$ ; $B.z∈GF_p^2$. This is useful for simplifying computations on $A$ or $B$ like scalar multiplying or squaring.
However when the suborder/subgroup $s$ from $GF_p^6$ doesn’t exists in $GF_p^2$, why does solving the 3 discrete logarithm between each subfield element that are

dlog of $A.x$ and $B.x$
dlog of $A.y$ and $B.y$
dlog of $A.z$ and $B.z$

doesn’t help establishing the discrete log of the whole $A$ and $B$ ?

I might also be wrong in the way it indeed helps since squaring starts by squaring each subfields.

Unclear: "suborder"?  Also a double negative in last sentence. What is "discrete logarithm between"? Please define your terms.

@kodlu the order of a finite field is $p^{power}-1$. I meant subgroup. I don t see a double negative in the last sentence.

I'm not sure why you didn't use $GF_p^3$ to illustrate this, but if I can try to extract what you're asking: suppose we have a finite field $K$ (such as $GF_p^6$) which is an extension of $F$ (such as $GF_p^2$). That means we can write $K = F[x]/p(x)$, i.e., every element in $K$ can be written as a polynomial of elements in $F$. So for $A,B\in K$, we could write
$$ A = A_0 + A_1x + A_2x^2 + \dots + A_{d-1}x^{d-1}$$
where $d$ is the degree of the extension. I think that's what you're describing by $A.x$, $A.y$, $A.z$.
In this format we can represent $A$ as $(A_0,A_1,\dots, A_{d-1})$ and then addition can be done component-wise. But multiplication cannot be done component-wise in this format, so discrete log cannot be done component-wise. That is, the components of $AB$ are not $(A_0B_0,A_1B_1,\dots, A_{d-1}B_{d-1})$. Multiplications mix up the components in this representation.
Is there a different way to represent some element that would make multiplication (and thus discrete log) function component-wise? If we're restricted to a prime-order subgroup, then no: if there is some representation of $A$ as $(A_0,A_1,\dots, A_r)$ such that multiplication works component-wise, then the multiplicative order of $A$ would be the least common multiple of the order of each $A_i$. If we're in a prime-order subgroup, then that tells us that least common multiple is some prime $p$, meaning the order of each $A_i$ is either $1$ or $p$. This means the discrete log is not going to be any easier, at least with standard techniques.
If we're not in a prime-order subgroup, then we can do Pohlig-Hellman, which looks sort of like what you're describing.

Error! Even with cubic extension fields, multiplications and Forbenius and exponentiations can be done component wise that don t depend on any characteristic of the underlying order https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/crypto/bn256/cloudflare/gfp6.go. The rules are then more difficult. So this isn t for this reason. After all maybe I m wrong and it can even help.

No? Nothing in the code you linked gives component-wise multiplication. The Frobenius endomorphism is exceptional since $(a+b)^p = a^p+b^p$ in a field of characteristic $p$, but that doesn't help with general exponents.

The code allowing to peform component wise multiplications in here https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/24c5493becc5f39df501d2b02989801471abdafa/crypto/bn256/cloudflare/gfp6.go#L94. Exponentiation is peformed through squaring.

That's not what component-wise means. Component-wise means that if $A=(A.x,A.y,A.z)$ and $B=(B.x,B.y,B.z)$, then the components of $AB$ are $(A.x\cdot B.x,A.y\cdot B.y,A.z\cdot B.z)$. The code you linked to computes the components of $AB$ as a function of the components of $A$ and $B$, but that function does not "split". That is: If we want to know the "$x$" component of $A^n$, we cannot compute it just from $A.x$ (unless $n$ is a multiple of $p$).
